# combination join query table 1 varchar-column-with-int-column for table 2

Tags: postgresql, oracle

```
SELECT *
FROM SD_TRAVEL_HISTORY a,
     TRAVEL_CORRECTION_ORDER_LI b
where a.transaction_ref = TO_NUMBER(b.travel_transaction_id)
;
```

`transaction_ref` --number column

`travel_transaction_id` --varchar

need help on this above query is invalid

Comment: Oracle or Postgres? Please only tag the DBMS that you are really using.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/) and review [ask]. Critical for this question is the full and complete error message, as text - **no images** or a complete description of `invalid`. Further, table definition(s) (ddl) and sample data, also text, and expected results helpful. Note: since you want compere a text column to a numeric column, you might be better off converting the numeric to text. You **will** at  dome point wind up with  a `travel_transaction_id` that cannot be converted to a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

What's *invalid* in that query? I'd say it is OK (more or less) . Any errors? If so, which ones? Why do you think we should *guess* what's wrong?

---

Anyway, here's what I think: if you're on Oracle, you got `ORA-01722` (invalid number) error because your *noble* intention to match datatypes failed as database wasn't able to "convert" `b.travel_transaction_id` to a valid numeric value. For example:

```
SQL> select to_number('12a') from dual;
select to_number('12a') from dual
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

So, what to do? Go vice versa and convert number to a string!

```
select *
from sd_travel_history a,
     travel_correction_order_li b
where to_char(a.transaction_ref) = b.travel_transaction_id);
```

---

Or, as suggested in comments, explicitly join tables as

```
select *
from sd_travel_history a join travel_correction_order_li b
  on to_char(a.transaction_ref) = b.travel_transaction_id);
```